# How can i add Scanner Port

Tags: c, sockets, server, client, port

i have code create with c and socket of display to adress conecting in my server , now i need to do some code for scanner port in one of there adresses, the input is start port and end port and the server scan ports who connecting in one of adress local
Please i neeeeeeeeeeeed Help
someone who help me

```
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define MAX 80 
#define PORT 8080 
#define SA struct sockaddr 

// Driver function 
int main() 
{ 
        int sockfd, connfd, len ,start , end;
        struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli; 
        struct sockaddr_in addr_remote;
    char ips[2][20];
    char hostname[30];

    // socket create and verification 
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    if (sockfd == -1) { 
    printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
    } 
    else
    printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 

    // assign IP, PORT 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    // Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification 
    if ((bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) { 
    printf("socket bind failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
    } 
    else
    printf("Socket successfully binded..\n"); 

    // Now server is ready to listen and verification 

    if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0) { 
    printf("Listen failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
    } 
    else
    printf("Server listening..\n"); 
    len = sizeof(cli); 

    // Accept the data packet from client and verification 
 for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&addr_remote, &len); 
    if (connfd < 0) { 
    printf("server acccept failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
    } 
    else
    printf("server acccept the client...\n"); 
    strcpy(ips[i], inet_ntoa(addr_remote.sin_addr));
    }

    // Display Ip 
   for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    printf("%s \n",ips[i]);}

    // Scan PORT

        //Get the hostname to scan
        printf("Enter hostname or IP : ");
        gets(hostname);

        //Get start port number
        printf("Enter start port number : ");
        //To Handle the Input
        int data;
        data = scanf("%d",&start);

        //Get end port number
        printf("Enter end port number : ");
        int data2 = scanf("%d" , &end);


    // After Display close the socket 
    close(sockfd); 

}
```

Comment: If you wish to 'scan' the addresses of the two connected clients, why are you scanffing in another IP address?  What are you 'scanning' for?  TCP Servers?

Comment: just i test now !! , But how can i scan port of one of two adress please ?